# App not compatible with your device. ALL devices

Tags: java, android, device

After publishing my app, I got the message it's not compatible with my device.
even though I test it in the same device.
The "error" message is showing for everyone who tries to download the app, like it's not compatible with your device.
Folow the Gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ths.dev.cadeoprefeito"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3'
    //FirebaseCORE
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    //FirebaseDatabase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
    //ADSFirebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:16.0.1'
    //FirebaseAUTH
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
    //FirebaseStorage
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.3'
    //FirebaseUI
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
}
```

the Manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ths.dev.cadeoprefeito">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Permissões para foto -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.MapsActivity"
            android:label="Cadê o Prefeito"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I don't know what i can do. Any help?

Comment: can you share your app url of play store ?

Comment: i get it, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ths.dev.cadeoprefeito

Comment: Yeah, this one! I updated what the guy said and I'm still waiting for GP to update and try again.

Answer (score 5):

You should add **`android:required="false"`** in `android:name="android.hardware.camera2"` section.

> When you declare [**`android:required="false"`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element) for a feature, it means that
>   the application prefers to use the feature if present on the device,
>   but that it is designed to function without the specified feature, if
>   necessary.

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: For real? That's it? haha... Ok, I'll try and update you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

don't think `android.hardware.camera2` is the reason, which is commonly available on current devices - when not requiring it, one has to provide the legacy `camera` as a fallback option (with a maps and splash-screen activity, I'd rather wonder for what it shall be good for). the reason is rather: a) add the [supports-screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element) element to the `Manifest.xml`... because without it, no single screen size is being supported. and b) add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the bottom of the file.

[image: Google Play Store screenshot]

Comment: @ThiagoHenriqueDosSantos added a screenshot; it's supported on small screens... there may be some delay in between pushing the release and it being available in the Play Store. also see the pre-release checks, which may hint for things to improve.

Comment: It's working now... I think it was the delay. The problem is that the map doesn't appear when I download from Google Store, but when I compile or debug from Android Studio to my mobile, everything works perfectly.

Comment: @ThiagoHenriqueDosSantos have a look at the ProGuard configuration - and especially the output of that. you could build a release build with debug enabled (not to publish).